# SOAP web service and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, soapui

I'm trying to secure a SOAP web service with Spring Security 3.

This is my configuration:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDB"
         expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
     <http-basic />
     <logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>

<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
   <authentication-provider>
      <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Tomcat is configured for SSL, a keystore containing the server's private key is used. I'm testing the web service with SOAPUI. I've created a request that perform one of the operation provided by the service. In the Auth section, I've added the username and password of the test user according to the value present in the database. After sending the request, I expect that a session is created and that there is no need to authenticate again. In the HTTP response, the JSESSIONID cookie is present. When a web site is secured by the same mechanism, the user enters its credentials only once until its session is expired when he needs to reauthenticate.

What's wrong with my config?

---

EDIT: I forgot to add that when I resend the same request multiple times, the received JSESSIONID cookie has always a different value. Should I expect it to be the same for a given session?

Comment: Is SoapUI correctly sending back the cookie?

Comment: @artbristol It seems that a new JSESSIONID cookie is generated for each message sent by SOAPUI. I don't know why.

Comment: That'll be because SoapUI isn't returning the original cookie with each new request.

Answer (score 0):

Under TestCase Options you need to turn on the "Maintain HTTP Session" option. Unfortunately, you have to do this for each testcase separately, there is no global option for this.